# ¿PyQt4 error no modulo?

Tags: python, python-2.7

tengo un problema. Quiero trabajar con PyQt4, pero cuando lo importo me sale un error:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
  from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Descargué e instalé `PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x64.exe`, *Windows 64-bit installer* y la versión de Python que tengo es `2.7.9`

Comment: Hola Yeison, ¿mi respuesta resolvió tu problema? Haznos saber si conseguiste finalmente importar PyQt4 o instalaste PyQt5 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

Puedes ver en qué rutas se están cargando los paquetes. 
Actualiza tu pregunta con la salida de este comando, y busca en tu ordenador dónde se ha instalado PyQt4.

Con

```
>>> help('modules')
```

puedes obtener una lista de paquetes disponibles.

Por último, si tienes oportunidad de usar PyQt5, ya se puede instalar usando pip:

https://pypi.io/project/PyQt5/

Usando

```
> pip install PyQt5
```